# Is there a time limit on App Store receipt verification?

Tags: iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase

Is there a time limit on how long we have to verify App Store receipts?
Can I verify a receipt I have today, 5 years from now?

In other words, will Apple's receipt verifier ever say that a valid a receipt is invalid  just because the receipt is old?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I have not yet seen a written guarantee that we will be able to verify receipts through all eternity, I expect they will allow for it for a long time from now.

Even if they decide to switch to some other sort of mechanism one day, they will have to phase it out slowly to allow migrating content because it's just too important and businesses are relying heavily on it.

But, as I said, there's no guarantee. They deprecated access to the UDID even though people were relying heavily on that one, too.